# Why does a query where basic expression true == true return no documents?

Tags: mongodb

Why does this query return no documents?

```
db.records.find({ true: true })
```

Are basic expressions not allowed in MQL?

Comment: Do the documents contains true field? If not how you can expect  them to be returned?

Comment: if considering basic set theory all documents in the set are eligible upon the conditions.  In this example true is always equal to true, and as such all records are eligible for that subset of the original set.  Consider the equivalent SQL `select * from records where 1=1`. In this example all records in the table `records` will return.  But, to answer your question more succinctly, no, there is no field called 'true'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic mongo query is about object matching. Your `{ true: true }` query will find documents where the "true" field is `true`.

If you want expression equivalence, check out [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/):

```
db.records.find({ $expr: { $eq: [true , true] } })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
db.records.find( { "_id": { "$ne": "" } } )
```

This query searches the records collection and returns all the records where the id field is not a blank string. This will return all records in the collection because the id field, in most cases, is auto-generated and therefore never blank.

Comment: Thanks Josh.  I can run db.records.find({}) and get all records.  I am questioning the ability to use basic expressions, or lack thereof.